Change day of week of a Windows scheduled task from the commandline
Is there any way to change an existing scheduled task's day-of-the-week setting from the commandline? schtasks /create has a /D option for MON/TUE/etc, but schtasks /change throws ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '/D'.
The best option I could come up with is exporting the task as XML, editing it, then re-importing. Surely there's a better way? (I mean maybe not, these are built-in Windows CLI tools after all so I do largely expect huge deficiencies, but I'd love to be proven wrong.)

Have you looked into PowerShell as an option for modifying? Perhaps you should read the settings from an existing task, create a new task with the required options, and delete the old one?

It could be helpful, look at this article: How to Change Day-of-the-Week Setting for Scheduled Tasks in Windows Command Line
